Oralce JSON_TRANSFORM, set/insert/append not working
Why this:
with j(jval) AS
(
select JSON_SERIALIZE('{"contract" :{"contract-type" : "P",
    "contract-id" : 123451,
    "proposal-no" : "123456",
    "serial-no" : "serialasd922",
    "product-code" : "s093",
    "contract-sign-dt" : "2016-12-01T00:00:00",
    "contract-start-dt" : "2016-12-09T00:00:00"
  }
}' pretty) from dual
)
SELECT   json_transform(jval, insert '$.contract[*].x' = '50' pretty)
FROM     j

is not working? I'm Trying to insert new value under $.contract.
Set with insert on missing also not working, but when it comes to SET to update existing field - everything's fine.

It works since Oracle21c, but not in Oracle19c https://sqlize.online/sql/oracle21/1f1752e1bcb589403e429e631abcf09f/

You are trying to insert '$.contract[*].x', but contract is an object not an array, so the [*] shouldn't be there.
Use insert '$.contract.x' = 50 instead.
with j(jval) AS
(
select JSON_SERIALIZE('{"contract" :{"contract-type" : "P",
    "contract-id" : 123451,
    "proposal-no" : "123456",
    "serial-no" : "serialasd922",
    "product-code" : "s093",
    "contract-sign-dt" : "2016-12-01T00:00:00",
    "contract-start-dt" : "2016-12-09T00:00:00"
  }
}' pretty) from dual
)
SELECT   json_transform(jval, insert '$.contract.x' = '50' pretty)
FROM     j




JSON_TRANSFORM(JVAL,INSERT'$.CONTRACT.X'='50'PRETTY)




{  "contract" :  {    "contract-type" : "P",    "contract-id" : 123451,    "proposal-no" : "123456",    "serial-no" : "serialasd922",    "product-code" : "s093",    "contract-sign-dt" : "2016-12-01T00:00:00",    "contract-start-dt" : "2016-12-09T00:00:00",    "x" : "50"  }}



fiddle
I'm not sure why set works with or without the [*].

Similar to your comment on set, insert also works on an array of objects with or without the [*] fiddle.

I don't have an Oracle 19 server to test on but in Oracle 21, you want $.contract.x and not $.contract[*].x:
SELECT   json_transform(jval, insert '$.contract.x' = '50' pretty)
FROM     j

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE j (jval CLOB CHECK (jval IS JSON));

INSERT INTO j (jval) VALUES (
  JSON_SERIALIZE(
   '{"contract" :{
    "contract-type" : "P",
    "contract-id" : 123451,
    "proposal-no" : "123456",
    "serial-no" : "serialasd922",
    "product-code" : "s093",
    "contract-sign-dt" : "2016-12-01T00:00:00",
    "contract-start-dt" : "2016-12-09T00:00:00"
  }
}'
    pretty
  )
);

Outputs:



JSON_TRANSFORM(JVAL,INSERT'$.CONTRACT.X'='50'PRETTY)




{  "contract" :  {    "contract-type" : "P",    "contract-id" : 123451,    "proposal-no" : "123456",    "serial-no" : "serialasd922",    "product-code" : "s093",    "contract-sign-dt" : "2016-12-01T00:00:00",    "contract-start-dt" : "2016-12-09T00:00:00",    "x" : "50"  }}




To get $.contract[*].x to work then contract would need to be an array of objects that looked like {"contract" :[{},{}]} and then after:
SELECT   json_transform(jval, insert '$.contract[*].x' = '50' pretty)
FROM     j

The output would be:



JSON_TRANSFORM(JVAL,INSERT'$.CONTRACT[*].X'='50'PRETTY)




{  "contract" :  [    {      "x" : "50"    },    {      "x" : "50"    }  ]}



fiddle
